# Running scanners inside if satement runs but does not save the method value

Tags: java

I have been working on a project this past few days. I run in to some weird problems with scanners.

The goal is to run an infinite loop in scanning users input and passing those input as a parameter for a method.

What I know is that the code works if the items are defined explicitly without the use of scanners as per the code below:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class TrackerConsole {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        Scanner scanInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        LifestyleTracker app = new LifestyleTracker();

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a command");
            String userInput = scanInput.next();
            if (userInput.contains("food")) {
                System.out.println(app.addFood("pasta", 2000)); 
            }
            else if (userInput.contains("eat")) {
                System.out.println(app.eat("pasta", 20));
            }
            else if (userInput.contains("report")) {
                System.out.println(app.report());
            }
            i++;
        } while (i < 10);
    }
}
```

[image: Here's the sample output calling the commands food, eat and report]

But here's the weird part when I add scanners inside the if statement like the code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TrackerConsole {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        Scanner scanInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        LifestyleTracker app = new LifestyleTracker();

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a command");
            String userInput = scanInput.next();
            if (userInput.contains("food")) {
                System.out.println("Add new food?");
                String getFood = scanInput.next();
                System.out.println("How many calories");
                double getCalories = scanInput.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(app.addFood(getFood, getCalories)); 
            }
            else if (userInput.contains("eat")) {
                System.out.println(app.eat("pasta", 20));
            }
            else if (userInput.contains("report")) {
                System.out.println(app.report());
            }
            i++;
        } while (i < 10);
    }
}
```

Notice when I called the command 'eat' it throws me an error saying that its not in the collections while before that I called 'food' which says 'food is added successfully'. It seems that my method call is not saved when the loop resets. This is the out put of calling the same items in the terminal:

[image: This is the output]

I hope someone can help me with this

Comment: I think your answer could be explained by why you are using `contains()` to test the input instead of checking for equality. Perhaps the scanned data contains some sort of terminator. When you pass `"pasta"` to the `eat()` function, it may not be matching what was added.

Comment: There's missing code here, so this is unanswerable. How are you adding and "eating" the food? You may be doing something wrong that's very trivial like comparing strings with `==` instead of `equals`.

Comment: I tried to use " == " but it doesn't read the input and it skips the if code blocks. I also tried to use .equals to check for equality and it works fine as well